# Replacing item in ArrayList with listIterator - cannot solve listIterator.set()

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have problems with replacing an item in my arraylist. I've searched for the soultion and found that it is being done by listIterator. So I wanted to implement that, but somehow the "set" method for iterator is not available. Why? The whole thing is happening in the `@Repository` in my spring mvc app.

```
private List<Car> listOfCars = new ArrayList<Car>();
listOfCars.add(...);
listOfCars.add(...);
listOfCars.add(...);

public void update(Car car) {
    Iterator<Car> listIterator = listOfCars.listIterator();
    while (listIterator.hasNext()) {
        Car c = listIterator.next();

        if(c.equals(car)){
            listIterator.set(car);
        }
```

}

Program cannot solve `listIterator.set()` - this is nto available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to use `ListIterator` methods, use the `ListIterator` type for your `listIterator` variable:

```
ListIterator<Car> listIterator = listOfCars.listIterator();
```

`Iterator` doesn't have a `set` method.

Comment: that was what was missing. After long hours in front of computer it's easy to overlook obvious things. However, now i get `ConcurrentModificationException`. I thought using iterator prevents me from having such problems.

Comment: @bartuomiei Not sure why you got that exception. Is it possible you are having multiple threads modifying that ArrayList? Anyway, you can replace your loop with `int index = listOfCards.indexOf(car);if (index >= 0) {listOfCars.set(index,car);}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29) method once you know the index of element you want to replace.

```
listOfCars.set(INDEX, car);
```